# How can i download converted svf or other(ifc) file from autodesk-forge

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are converted rvt file to svf and opened it on autodesk forge viewer. And now we want to download this converted sfv file. How we can do this??

This is my code for converting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNv4f.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant code in de question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few samples to get you started:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs
- https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io

Basically you will need to parse the [manifest](GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeUrn) and follow the paths to download the resources via [GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeUrn](GET :urn/manifest/:derivativeUrn)

Comment: have you another solution for this task its not working